# Read all folders in Java and continue operation

Tags: java, encryption

This Java decryption (AES128) works,
but I have two problems:

1. Any time a file is corrupt, the remaining files aren't decrypted. (If there are 10 files and file number 4 is corrupt, the files 5–10 aren't decrypted.)
2. How can I read all folders in a folder?

```
public class DecoderGui extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form DecoderGui
 */

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add( new DecoderGui());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setResizable( false );
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    frame.setVisible(true);
}     

public DecoderGui() {
    initComponents();
}




@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    keyFile = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    sourceDirectory = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    destinationDirectory = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    keyButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    sourceButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    destinationButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    decryptButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    exitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    message = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Schutzstaffel Decryption");

    destinationDirectory.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            destinationDirectoryActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    keyButton.setText("Key File");
    keyButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            keyButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    sourceButton.setText("Browse");
    sourceButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            sourceButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    destinationButton.setText("Save");
    destinationButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            destinationButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    decryptButton.setText("Decrypt");
    decryptButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            decryptButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    exitButton.setText("Exit");
    exitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            exitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                                .addComponent(decryptButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                                .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(message, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 436, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(keyFile, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 299, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(sourceDirectory)
                                .addComponent(destinationDirectory))
                            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(keyButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(destinationButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addComponent(sourceButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(145, 145, 145)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 212, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(31, 31, 31)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(keyFile, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(keyButton))
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(sourceDirectory, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(sourceButton))
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(destinationDirectory, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(destinationButton))
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(message)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(decryptButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(exitButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(82, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void exitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    System.exit(0);
}                                          

private void decryptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    try {
        if(keyFile.getText() == null || keyFile.getText().equals("")) {
            message.setText("Please select the key file");
        }
        if(sourceDirectory.getText() == null || sourceDirectory.getText().equals("")) {
            message.setText("Please select the source folder");
        }
        if(destinationDirectory.getText() == null || destinationDirectory.getText().equals("")) {
            message.setText("Please select the destination folder");
        }

        Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

        File sourcedir = new File(sourceDirectory.getText());
        File destinationdir = new File(destinationDirectory.getText());

    //    System.out.println(seeder);

        String seeder = new String(decoder.getFileDataToStream(keyFile.getText()));

        System.out.println(seeder);
        File[] directoryListing = sourcedir.listFiles();
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                System.out.println(child.getCanonicalPath());
                byte[] inputstream = decoder.getFileDataToStream(child.getCanonicalPath());
                byte[] outputstream = decoder.decrypt(seeder, inputstream);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationDirectory.getText()+File.separator+new String(Base64.decodeBase64(child.getName())));
                fos.write(outputstream);
                fos.close();

            }
            message.setText("Decryption done");
        } else {
            message.setText("Error while Listing the Source Directory Files");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}                                             

private void keyButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Key File");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
            System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
            keyFile.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
}                                         

private void sourceButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Source Folder");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
            System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
            sourceDirectory.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
}                                            

private void destinationButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose Destination Folder");
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
            System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
            destinationDirectory.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
    }
}                                                 

private void destinationDirectoryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
    When there is an error in decrypting the file you code exits the for loop, hence other files are not decrypted see the corrected code below, and add your code in place of ToDo:

```
private void decryptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        try {
            if(keyFile.getText() == null || keyFile.getText().equals("")) {
                message.setText("Please select the key file");
            }
            if(sourceDirectory.getText() == null || sourceDirectory.getText().equals("")) {
                message.setText("Please select the source folder");
            }
            if(destinationDirectory.getText() == null || destinationDirectory.getText().equals("")) {
                message.setText("Please select the destination folder");
            }

            Decoder decoder = new Decoder();

            File sourcedir = new File(sourceDirectory.getText());
            File destinationdir = new File(destinationDirectory.getText());

        //    System.out.println(seeder);

            String seeder = new String(decoder.getFileDataToStream(keyFile.getText()));

            System.out.println(seeder);
            File[] directoryListing = sourcedir.listFiles();
            if (directoryListing != null) {
                for (File child : directoryListing) {
                    try{
                        System.out.println(child.getCanonicalPath());
                        byte[] inputstream = decoder.getFileDataToStream(child.getCanonicalPath());
                        byte[] outputstream = decoder.decrypt(seeder, inputstream);
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationDirectory.getText()+File.separator+new String(Base64.decodeBase64(child.getName())));
                        fos.write(outputstream);
                        fos.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        // ToDo: handle the case when file was not decrypted
                    }
                }
                message.setText("Decryption done");
            } else {
                message.setText("Error while Listing the Source Directory Files");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DecoderGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

Problem 2: Get all Folders inside the Folders. complete folder hierarchy

```
LinkedList<String> folders = new LinkedList<String>();

folders.add("c:\\");

while(!folders.isEmpty()){

    File file = new File(folders.poll());

    if(file.listFiles()!=null)
        for(File dir:file.listFiles()){

            if(dir.isDirectory()){
                folders.add(dir.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("Folder " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: problem 1 tested show message "Decryption done" but after decryption don't have file (decrypted) in folder output

Comment: file for which error occurs will not be decrypted that you need to handle in catch clause, are all the files not getting decrypted?